List of all entitlements on Apple systems
Is there a list of all entitlements, past and present, recognized on macOS and all other Apple operating systems? Or a list that covers at least half of them? I can't find one anywhere and the entitlement database tool is unusable. If there isn't one, then would I be able to find a list of all of them inside AppleMobileFileIntegrity.kext/Contents/MacOS/AppleMobileFileIntegrity?

What problem are you trying to solve?  Is the list from developer.apple.com not comprehensive?  The jtool2 tool that the author of the web page you reference created seems quite comprehensive as well.

@MarcWilson The problem I am trying to solve: find out what all the existing entitlements are.

@MarcWilson jtool2 is not useful here because it isn't a list nor does it provide one. It just extracts the ones included in an executable.

@Melab if you have an Apple Developer Membership, you can use a Code Level Technical Support request to ask for all the entitlements.

A sizeable but incomplete list of Apple documented entitlements is published in Bundle Resources / Entitlements. An extract of the key values is below.
There are other entitlements but these are not documented and may change between versions of macOS.
To find undocumented entitlements, use the code signing tools to extract entitlements from Apple's executables' signatures. This task has already been done by the linked site in your question.
New OSX Book's OS X/iOS Entitlement Database is likely the best practical enumeration of Apple entitlements. The site mentions the database's source for macOS 13 as:

Loaded 1709 executables and 2633 entitlements for MacOS.

This number far exceeds the formally documented entitlements below:


com.apple.developer.applesignin
com.apple.developer.aps-environment
com.apple.developer.associated-appclip-app-identifiers
com.apple.developer.associated-domains
com.apple.developer.associated-domains.applinks.read-write
com.apple.developer.authentication-services.autofill-credential-provider
com.apple.developer.automated-device-enrollment.add-devices
com.apple.developer.automatic-assessment-configuration
com.apple.developer.avfoundation.multitasking-camera-access
com.apple.developer.browser.app-installation
com.apple.developer.carplay-audio
com.apple.developer.carplay-charging
com.apple.developer.carplay-communication
com.apple.developer.carplay-maps
com.apple.developer.carplay-messaging
com.apple.developer.carplay-parking
com.apple.developer.carplay-quick-ordering
com.apple.developer.ClassKit-environment
com.apple.developer.contacts.notes
com.apple.developer.default-data-protection
com.apple.developer.device-information.user-assigned-device-name
com.apple.developer.devicecheck.appattest-environment
com.apple.developer.exposure-notification
com.apple.developer.family-controls
com.apple.developer.fileprovider.testing-mode
com.apple.developer.game-center
com.apple.developer.group-session
com.apple.developer.healthkit
com.apple.developer.healthkit.access
com.apple.developer.healthkit.background-delivery
com.apple.developer.healthkit.recalibrate-estimates
com.apple.developer.homekit
com.apple.developer.icloud-container-development-container-identifiers
com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment
com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers
com.apple.developer.icloud-services
com.apple.developer.in-app-identity-presentment
com.apple.developer.in-app-identity-presentment.merchant-identifiers
com.apple.developer.in-app-payments
com.apple.developer.journal.allow
com.apple.developer.kernel.extended-virtual-addressing
com.apple.developer.kernel.increased-memory-limit
com.apple.developer.location.push
com.apple.developer.mail-client
com.apple.developer.managed-app-distribution.install-ui
com.apple.developer.maps
com.apple.developer.marketplace.app-installation
com.apple.developer.matter.allow-setup-payload
com.apple.developer.media-device-discovery-extension
com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotConfiguration
com.apple.developer.networking.manage-thread-network-credentials
com.apple.developer.networking.multicast
com.apple.developer.networking.multipath
com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension
com.apple.developer.networking.slicing.appcategory
com.apple.developer.networking.slicing.trafficcategory
com.apple.developer.networking.vmnet
com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api
com.apple.developer.networking.wifi-info
com.apple.developer.nfc.hce
com.apple.developer.nfc.hce.default-contactless-app
com.apple.developer.nfc.hce.iso7816.select-identifier-prefixes
com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats
com.apple.developer.on-demand-install-capable
com.apple.developer.parent-application-identifiers
com.apple.developer.pass-type-identifiers
com.apple.developer.playable-content
com.apple.developer.sensitivecontentanalysis.client
com.apple.developer.sensorkit.reader.allow
com.apple.developer.severe-vehicular-crash-event
com.apple.developer.siri
com.apple.developer.storekit.external-link.account
com.apple.developer.storekit.external-purchase
com.apple.developer.storekit.external-purchase-link
com.apple.developer.sustained-execution
com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier
com.apple.developer.upi-device-validation
com.apple.developer.user-management
com.apple.developer.usernotifications.filtering
com.apple.developer.video-subscriber-single-sign-on
com.apple.developer.weatherkit
com.apple.developer.web-browser
com.apple.developer.web-browser.public-key-credential
com.apple.external-accessory.wireless-configuration
com.apple.security.application-groups
com.apple.security.hypervisor
com.apple.security.smartcard
com.apple.security.virtualization
com.apple.smoot.subscriptionservice
com.apple.vm.device-access
com.apple.vm.hypervisor
com.apple.vm.networking


